# how can i substract my var outside of addEventListener function scope

Tags: javascript

I was making this Tic Tac Toe game. added eventListener so when i click on it my turn got to subtract by 1 the problem is the subtracted `giliranX` won't carry over to the global var i have tried adding return but it has nowhere to return to. is there any way i can do this without put onclick on the HTML?

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
const button2 = document.getElementById("button2")
const button3 = document.getElementById("button3")
const button4 = document.getElementById("button4")
const button5 = document.getElementById("button5")
const button6 = document.getElementById("button6")
const button7 = document.getElementById("button7")
const button8 = document.getElementById("button8")
const button9 = document.getElementById("button9")

var giliranX = 3,
    giliranO = 3,
    untukCek = "";
const turnX = document.getElementById("header1")
const turnO = document.getElementById("header2")


if (giliranX === giliranO){
  button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button1.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button2.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button3.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button3.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button4.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button4.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button5.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button5.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button6.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button6.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button7.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button7.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button8.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button8.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
button9.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button9.innerHTML = "X";
  giliranX -= 1;
})
}else if(giliranO > giliranX){
  button1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button1.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button2.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button3.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button3.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button4.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button4.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button5.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button5.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button6.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button6.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button7.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button7.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button8.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button8.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
  button9.addEventListener("click", function(){
  button9.innerHTML = "O";
  giliranO -= 1;
})
}

//Turn X and O are still 3 even after click
 console.log(giliranX)
 console.log(giliranO)
turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
```

```css
.boardwrap{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header1">Turn X =</h1>
<h1 id="header2">Turn Y =</h1>
<div class="boardwrap">
  <button id="button1"></button>
  <button id="button2"></button>
  <button id="button3"></button>
  <button id="button4"></button>
  <button id="button5"></button>
  <button id="button6"></button>
  <button id="button7"></button>
  <button id="button8"></button>
  <button id="button9"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so you are doing your if statements once on load, Not per click, So its always going to be the same result.

```
var giliranX = 3,
    giliranO = 3,
    untukCek = "";
    
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    turnX = document.getElementById("header1")
    turnO = document.getElementById("header2")

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (giliranX === giliranO) {
            button.innerHTML = "X";
            giliranX = giliranX -= 1;
        } else if (giliranO > giliranX) {
            button.innerHTML = "O";
            giliranO = giliranO -= 1;
        }
        turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
        turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
    });
});

turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
```

for good measure remove the click event once triggered.

```
var giliranX = 3,
    giliranO = 3,
    untukCek = "";
    
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    turnX = document.getElementById("header1")
    turnO = document.getElementById("header2")

buttons.forEach(button => {
    const clickHandler = () => {
        if (giliranX === giliranO) {
            button.innerHTML = "X";
            giliranX = giliranX -= 1;
        } else if (giliranO > giliranX) {
            button.innerHTML = "O";
            giliranO = giliranO -= 1;
        }
        turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
        turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
        button.removeEventListener('click',clickHandler);
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
});

turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
```

in response to moving the headings into its own function

```
var giliranX = 3,
    giliranO = 3,
    untukCek = "";
    
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    turnX = document.getElementById("header1")
    turnO = document.getElementById("header2")

buttons.forEach(button => {
    const clickHandler = () => {
        if (giliranX === giliranO) {
            button.innerHTML = "X";
            giliranX = giliranX -= 1;
        } else if (giliranO > giliranX) {
            button.innerHTML = "O";
            giliranO = giliranO -= 1;
        }
        setHeadings();
        button.removeEventListener('click',clickHandler);
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
});

function setHeadings() {
    turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
    turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
}

setHeadings();
```

Comment: is it possible to use the Global `turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX`
`turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO` (Bottom) , instead of the function scoped one? for example if i use declared function `function name(){ giliranX = 10}` Then when invoked in global scope `name()` it will replace giliranX declared at the top. isn't clicking with addEventListener(click, function) invoke the function? if so why it can't affect the global var declared at top of the page, I'm sorry if it sound stupid but please bear with me,Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you are after but no, Setting the variable name is not enough to change the HTML, once you set it its not reactive. for that you would need a library like vue.js, You can move the innerHTML sets into its own function but its just going to be doing the same. - ive updated my answer to do this,

Answer (score 0):

You use giliranX before change, i.e. you just add event listeners and they do what you told them, eventListnerer with 'O' will never be added, because you have condition before it. To fix it, you need to decide 'O' or 'X' inside eventListener, also I would suggest you to not make indifidual function for each button, imaginate if you need (and you really are) change all this listeners. let's fix it:

```js
const state = Array.from(Array(3), ()=>['','','']) // array 3x3 to remember the state

for (let index=1;index<=9;index++) {
  const button = document.getElementById(`button${index}`);
  button.addEventListener('click', ()=>processClick({index, node: button }))
}
let giliranX = 3;
let giliranO = 3;
let isX = true;
const turnX = document.getElementById("header1")
const turnO = document.getElementById("header2")
function processClick({index, node}) {
  const row = Math.floor((index-1)/3);
  const cell = (index - 1) % 3
  if (state[row][cell]) {
    return;
  }
  const label = isX ? 'X' : 'O';
  if (isX) {
    giliranX--;
    turnX.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranX
  } else {
    giliranO--;
    turnO.innerHTML = "Turn X = " + giliranO
  }
  
  
  state[row][cell] = label;
  node.innerText = label;
  isX = !isX;
}
```

```css
.boardwrap{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header1">Turn X =</h1>
<h1 id="header2">Turn Y =</h1>
<div class="boardwrap">
  <button id="button1"></button>
  <button id="button2"></button>
  <button id="button3"></button>
  <button id="button4"></button>
  <button id="button5"></button>
  <button id="button6"></button>
  <button id="button7"></button>
  <button id="button8"></button>
  <button id="button9"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain this code? `if (state[row][cell]) { return; }` Wouldn't it always be true since there are no compare or logic operator and end the function right away? I guess this is a code to prevent from replacing the inner html i.e `x` to `o` ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
        const button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
        const button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
        const button4 = document.getElementById("button4");
        const button5 = document.getElementById("button5");
        const button6 = document.getElementById("button6");
        const button7 = document.getElementById("button7");
        const button8 = document.getElementById("button8");
        const button9 = document.getElementById("button9");

        const btnReset  = document.getElementById("button-reset");
        const resultOut = document.getElementById("resultOut");
        const blockWrap = document.querySelector('.boardwrap');

        // Note: 1 == X; 2 == O;
        let currentXO = 1;

        // Note: 0 == Draw; 1 == Victory; 
        let resultGame = -1; 

        const arrCase = [   
          /* Note: horizont */
          [0,1,2],
          [3,4,5],
          [6,7,8],
          
          /* Note: vertical */
          [0,3,6],
          [1,4,7],
          [2,5,8],
          
          /* Note: diagonal */
          [0,4,8],
          [2,4,6],
        ];


        function checkEmptyBlock(){
            
            for( let i = 0; i < blockWrap.children.length; i++ )
                if( blockWrap.children[i].innerHTML == ""  && resultGame != 1 )
                    return false;

            return true;
        }


        // Note: Logic game.
        function logicGame(){
    
          for( let i in arrCase ){
            
            if( blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][0]].innerHTML == "X" && 
                blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][1]].innerHTML == "X" &&  
                blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][2]].innerHTML == "X" ){
               
                blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][0]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][1]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][2]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                
                resultGame = 1;
                
            // Note: result out.
                resultOut.innerHTML = "Result: Game Victory X!";
              return false; 
            }
                
            else if( blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][0]].innerHTML == "O" &&  
                         blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][1]].innerHTML == "O" &&  
                     blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][2]].innerHTML == "O" ){
                      
                     blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][0]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                       blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][1]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                       blockWrap.children[arrCase[i][2]].style.backgroundColor="green";
                      
                    resultGame = 1;
                    
                // Note: result out.
                    resultOut.innerHTML = `Result: Game Victory O!`;

                    return false;
                }    
            }

            if( checkEmptyBlock() ){
                    resultGame = 0;
                    resultOut.innerHTML = `Result: No victory in the game (^_^)`;

                for( let i=0; i < blockWrap.children.length; i++ ){
                    blockWrap.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        // Note: Event click any buttons in block.
        blockWrap.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
                    
            if( event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" ){

                
            
                if( resultGame == 1 || resultGame == 0 )
                    return;
              
                
                if( event.target.textContent === "" && currentXO === 1 ){
              
                    event.target.textContent = 'X';

                    if( logicGame() ) currentXO = 2; 
                }
                else if( event.target.textContent === "" && currentXO === 2 ){
                    
                    event.target.textContent = 'O';
                    
                    if( logicGame() ) currentXO = 1;    
                }
                
            }
        });


        // Note: Event clicked button reset game.
        btnReset.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
            currentXO = 1;
            resultGame = -1;
            resultOut.innerHTML = "Result: ";
            for( let i=0; i < blockWrap.children.length; i++ ){
                blockWrap.children[i].innerHTML="";
                blockWrap.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
        });
```

```css
.boardwrap{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="resultOut">Result: </h1>
    <h1>Menu: <button id="button-reset">RESET-GAME</button></h1>
    <div class="boardwrap">
      <button id="button1"></button>
      <button id="button2"></button>
      <button id="button3"></button>
      <button id="button4"></button>
      <button id="button5"></button>
      <button id="button6"></button>
      <button id="button7"></button>
      <button id="button8"></button>
      <button id="button9"></button>
    </div>
```